# Passing values ajax to php not in same page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Here is where I select my value

```
Company Name<br />
<select id="company" name="selected"> 


   <option value="">Value 1</option>
   <option value="">Value 1</option>

</select>
```

When I click this one I want it to have a modal like or facebox 
  <`a rel="facebox" id="getitems" href="ordersupply.php" >Order Item</a>`

My ajax code here note: when I alert this one it gives the value but cant find it in the `ordersupply` page

```
$("#getitems").click(function(){
 var x = document.getElementById("company").value;
 alert(x);
 $.ajax({
     url: "ordersupply.php",
     type: "POST",
     data: {"selected": x},
  success: function(response){
   console.log(response);

   }

  });
 });
```

I'll just make a simple php where I can echo in my page the selected value can anyone help me with this one :) It will be very much appreciated

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['selected']))
{
$value = $_POST['selected'];

echo $value;
}


?>
```

Comment: <select id="company" name="selected">  sorry guys if the question is cut huhu :( here's what it's in the first part of the code

Comment: please assign value in every option in select box.otherwise it will not return any value

Comment: Hi maam I did put it a value in every option but I just cant put my database code here It might get confusing sorry :( but the thought is there I get the value and it will alert and put success just cant get the value when it goes another page :(

Comment: What are you trying to do? I don't think that you fully understand how Ajax works. `echo $value` will not show anything on a page, it sends the value back to your script.

Comment: @simon so this will not be applicable sir? I was hoping that it might work huhu :(

Comment: I don't know what you want to do but I'm sure it's possible. Do you want to show the value on a new page? Or do you want to show the value on the current page?

Comment: value on the new page sir :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$.ajax({
     url: "ordersupply.php",
     type: "POST",
   contentType : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
     data: {"selected": x},
  success: function(response){
   console.log(response);

   }

  });
```

Comment: Sir I did try it right away but its doesnt affect anything huhu :(

Answer (score -1):

Check in browser (f12) for firefox and chrome in the network section what response you get. There is a good chance for 404 not found error.

Comment: Hi sir I look up to it but it was there tho :) thanks anyway sir